# How to install SASS on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: sass, visual-studio-code

I would like to ask you for an explanation on how to install SASS in Visual Studio Code.

I installed Ruby. I read a lot of comments on the internet, but nothing helped. I just think I've succeeded, but it gives me a mistake.

So please explain me step by step how to install it.

As a last resort, please recommend me another development environment where SASS installs easily and run. But I like it a lot VSC and don’t want to give it up.
1 View

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR Install an extension** : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.live-sass

Great thing about VS Code is their community and available extensions.

There is a great extension that I have linked above that will transpile your SCSS files to CSS in real time. It has a dependency, Live Server, which is great. With both these extensions you can make SCSS edits and see the edits you make reflect, live, in your browser

I previously used Ruby as well to make my CSS files. But I have not had any issues using this extension, yet. The extension and the new Dart SCSS are both javascript so im sure it will go well.